# How to set default timestamp as +1 month in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

What would I enter into the "as defined" in phpMyAdmin for a default value of a timestamp field, to get +1 month from today?

Using MySQL 5.6.17, php 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9, wampserver 2.5

I've tried

`1 month`

`strtotime('+1 month')`

Comment: Although your question is interesting, I would recommend to handle this via PHP and not via PMA. Let model handle this. If no value is passed, then insert `strtotime('+1 month')`

Comment: Have you tried using `date_trunc('day', NOW() + interval '1 month')` SQL Function.

Comment: Zander it says invalid. I suppose I will just run an update after inserting to fill in the field, as Bhavik mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've read, the phpmyadmin "as defined" value is basically what the `DEFAULT` value will be in the `CREATE TABLE` query.  If this is true, you can't actually provide a PHP function as your default value.  You then have (at least) two options.

One, you can just set the value when you `INSERT` into your database:

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month'));
```

And run your query:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myDate) VALUES ('{$myDate}');
```

(Though, you should use mysqli or PDO and data binding to set the value in your query.  C.f. https://www.php.net/pdo and https://www.php.net/mysqli).

Two, or you could create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTiggerName
BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.myDate = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

This is probably the closest to what you're trying to do.  It will set the `myDate` column to be `NOW() + 1 MONTH` whenever you insert a row into your `myTable` table.

In the above example, the trigger will always set `myDate`.  If you just want to set it if the column is null, you could try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTiggerName
BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.myDate IS NULL THEN
  SET NEW.myDate = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
END IF;
```

Comment: I haven't used triggers much, I think it probably makes more sense to just define it in the insert statement rather than phpMyAdmin anyways now that I think about it...

Comment: @Andrew Never too soon to try  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend handling this by your model, and not by SQL.

Try getting the date somewhat like this:

```
select timestamp + interval '2' day from xyz
```